# Copyright issues and credits of the base maps provided in the Quickmapservice plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis, license, arcgis-online-basemaps

I have used QGIS to create maps for a paper that I am going to submit to an academic journal. However, the journal requires that all figures should be under cc-by 4.0 license, while on the QGIS website, it is stated that "If not stated otherwise, all content is licensed under Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 license (CC BY-SA)".

Does that mean that I cannot use maps created by QGIS for this journal?

Also, I know that every user has to look for copyright permission and how to cite every base map respectively. I have used the ESRI satellite as the base map but found this [World Imagery](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=10df2279f9684e4a9f6a7f08febac2a9).

Does that mean that I cannot use these maps as the base maps if I am using QGIS instead of ArcGIS?

Comment: Legal questions are best asked of your own legal counsel, since free legal advice obtained on the Internet is worth less than it cost.

Comment: True, but I am quite sure there are more people having the same questions. All open access journals require figures under cc-by 4.0 as they are open to the public. What I am asking is what that sentence stated on the website meant. It doesn't seem possible that all maps created with QGIS can't be used for open access publication. Also, if the ESRI satellite is problematic to be used, why the plugin provides it. There can be people that are not aware of that and causing trouble to themselves.